# Private Net: Miners not mining pending transaction

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, pending-transactions

I am running a **private network**. I send a lot of transactions to geth with miner on (with 10 threads).

I could see my transactions getting mined properly for some time. And then I checked length of pending transactions (4142).

I stopped to send further transactions and run miner to clear this list of pending transactions. But the length of pending transactions is same even running miner for half an hour.

**The blocks are getting mined but no tx is added to the blocks.** I get empty object when I check transactions in any block (exculding first 42 blocks).

**Why the miner is not including ant transaction in blocks?**

**Edit 1**:

I have set set gas price 0 in my transactions. I have `miner.setGasPrice` to 0. The min gas price in genesis file to be 0. So I think this should not be realated to gas price.

Comment: Did you check the tx-nonces? Is it in strict order?

Comment: Yes, they are. All the txs are made from same account and nonce are in order.

Comment: I had a similar problem. It always comes in combination with gasPrice=0. Even rebroadcasting the transactions with the same nonce and higher price didn't help. However, after restarting the node, the pool got processed. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/geth-1-7-2-with-poa-transaction-still-pending-although-gas-price-has-been-incr

Comment: Restarting the blockchain has removed all blocks to 0. Now there are no blocks, no balances, no txs. :(

Comment: I meant simply restarting the node, not recreating the blockchain.

Comment: I did not init command.  I can see there is something wrong with geth 1.8, last 128 blocks are in memory, but I lost all of them